# Add class to divs after reload by targeting the "data" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I have four cards with the class of "card", but each one has a different data attribute: eyes, torso, arms and legs.

```
<div class="card" data-lesson="eyes">eyes</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="torso">torso</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="arms">arms</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="legs">legs</div>
```

Everytime the user clicks on a card, that card is given the class of "reading". Also, the browser looks at the data attribute of that card and stores it in an array, locally.

```
$(".card").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("reading")
    localStorage.setItem("readingCards" , readingCards)
 });
```

What I'm trying to do is: after the page reloads, give every card that matches the data attribute stored in the array the class of "reading" so that when the page refreshes the same cards will have this class.

Comment: jQuery allows you to use the `data()` function for data attributes so you can use `data('lesson')` instead of `attr('data-lesson')` ... just a side note

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I was plannig to change this after solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate through all elements having the `card` class with `each()` and check if the corresponding data attribute is included in the comma separated local storage string.

You can try this

https://jsfiddle.net/jL6o7dc4/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var readingCards = localStorage.getItem("readingCards")!==null?localStorage.getItem("readingCards"):'';

     $(".card").each(function(){

          if(readingCards.includes($(this).data("lesson"))){
            $(this).addClass("reading");
       }

     });

     $(".card").click(function(){

         $(this).addClass("reading");

         if(!readingCards.includes($(this).data("lesson"))){

         readingCards+=(readingCards.length>0?',':'')+$(this).data("lesson");
         localStorage.setItem("readingCards",readingCards);

    }

 });
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty good, but the problem is that, after the refresh, if I click on one of the cards that has the "reading" class, the local storage array resets, excluding all the other card data attributes and including only the clicked one data attribute. Probably because after the browser reload the readingCards array is included in the code as empty? (line 14 in the jsFiddle)

Comment: @VladSolomon I edited your code to be fully functional Check the fiddle and the code again.

Comment: Now this is amazing. Thank you for helping me with this, and I apologize if I wasn't very clear with my request the first time. Once again, thank you a lot.

Comment: Happy I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

The `HTML` is

```
<div class="card" data-lesson="eyes">Card 1</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="torso">Card 2</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="arms">Card 3</div>
<div class="card" data-lesson="legs">Card 4</div>
```

The Javascript is-

```
// On ready get the localStorage item and set the readings
var readingCards = localStorage.getItem('readingCards');
readingCards = typeof readingCards === 'string' && readingCards.length > 0 ? JSON.parse(readingCards) : [];

if (readingCards.length > 0) {
    $('.card').each(function(index) {
        let lesson = $(this).data('lesson');
        if (readingCards.indexOf(lesson) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass('reading');
        }
    });
}


$('.card').on('click', function() {

    if (!$(this).hasClass('reading')) {
        $(this).addClass('reading');
    }

    let lesson = $(this).data('lesson');

    if (readingCards.indexOf(lesson) === -1) {
        readingCards.push(lesson);
    }


    localStorage.setItem('readingCards', JSON.stringify(readingCards));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css selector ".card[data-lesson='AAA']" to uniquely identify the cards while iterating over the stored values.

```
var storedCards = localStorage.getItem("readingCards") || "";
storedCards = storedCards.split(',');
$.each(storedCards, function( index, value ) {
   $(".card[data-lesson='" + value + "']").addClass("reading");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it as an array in localstorage and then it is a simple loop to set the class by selecting items by the attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // read the localstorage and obtain the stored cards
  // if no value, just use an empty array
  var readingCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('readingCards') || '[]')
  // loop over the array and add the classes to our elements
  readingCards.forEach(function(value) {
    $('[data-lesson="' + value + '"]').addClass('reading')
  })
  // add the click event to the cards
  $(".card").on('click', function() {
    // get the card and toggle the class
    var card = $(this)
    card.toggleClass('reading')
    // select all the cards that are active and turn them into an array
    readingCards = $(".card.reading").map(function() {
      return this.dataset.lesson
    }).get()
    // set the array to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('readingCards', JSON.stringify(readingCards))
  })
})
```